# ASP.NET Forms Authentication. Determine if another user is online or not

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 web app, using FormsAuthentication, I want to determine if a user is still logged-in. Doing this for users who sign themselves out by clicking on the Log Out button is pretty straightforward - I can handle that event and set the flag in my database to indicate this user has signed out.

But I am not sure how to handle users who close the browser without signing them off voluntarily (by clicking the button).

I did some research but I don't think I can rely on `Session_End` event handler. Or can I?

Comment: you will see this pattern very often when user wont hit **Close** button. It could be because sometimes user don't want to and other times because user would lose the internet connection. Best way is you update `lastAccessTime` in your database table whenever user request for any operation. And you need to make a job which will check this table at every one minute for those users who haven't performed any activity since 10 or 15 mins. Then you just need to flag them off or **SESSION OUT**.

Comment: Im wondering, why FormsAuthentication when you have such a great template available? Just curious..

Comment: @RageCompex, you mean using ASP.NET Identity? Yes, I spent a long time trying to decide whether use that or stick with FormsAuthentication. But in the end I choose the latter mainly because simplicity.

Comment: I recommend you to use Identity, if using EF is not a problem then definitely!